# CSS absolute positioned container size autofit to relative positioned divs inside

Tags: html, css, position, expand

There are three divs: a container, with absolute position, top, left coords, and two divs inside, with relative positions, top and left coords.

I'd like to expand the container's size to the positioned div elements inside dynamically (so I don't like add width/height to the container element).

My code is:

https://jsfiddle.net/ruzds7bk/

css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  position: relative;

  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #c00;
}
```

html:

```
<!-- I'd like that the container's size would be fitted to its elements. -->
<div class="container" style="top: 80px; left: 20px;">
  <div class="box" style="top: 50px; left: 75px;">absolute</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 100px; left: 130px;">absolute</div>
</div>

<!-- Something like that, but without adding container's width and height. -->
<div class="container" style="top: 470px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 350px;">
  <div class="box" style="top: 100px; left: 75px;">absolute</div>
  <div class="box" style="top: 200px; left: 130px;">absolute</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better? "I want this, make it for me" is not really a question. What is your problem/what are you stuck on? And you can also paste your code in the question, this way, users don't have to go to a different site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `margin-top` and `margin-left` in place of `top` and `left` for the inner `.box` elements

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="top: 80px; left: 20px;">
  <div class="box" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 75px;">absolute</div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 130px;">absolute</div>
</div>
```